# Determining if all values in a list of lists are true or false

Tags: python, list

So basically I have a function that creates a list of lists, lets say I define 3 values to be in my list and each of those 3 values has a list of their own that contains 2 values, their number, and their availability, like so:

```py
[['Product 0', False, ], ['Product 1', False, ], ['Product 2', False,]]
```

Basically, I want to determine whether all values for availability are `True` or `False`, and I cannot seem to get it to work with `all()` as it apparently does not have to capability to check for values of lists inside of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this. Iterate the inner lists and extract the second value (True\False). Then use `all` to check all the values.

```
x = [['Product 0', False, ], ['Product 1', False, ], ['Product 2', False,]]

AllTrue  = all([e[1] for e in x])      # False
AllFalse = all([not e[1] for e in x])  # True
```

Comment: This is beautifully written. Nice solution!